# How to extract text, line by line from a txt file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a txt file like this :

```
audi lamborghini
ferrari
pagani
```

when I use this code :

```
with open("test.txt") as inp:
    data = set(inp.read().split())
```

this gives data as : `['pagani', 'lamborghini', 'ferrari', 'audi']`

What I want, is to extract text from the txt file, line by line such the output data is

`['audi lamborghini','ferrari','pagani']`

How this can be done ?

Comment: try `readlines` instead of `read`

Comment: Try `data = set(inp.read().splitlines())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data = inp.read().splitlines()
```

You *could* do

```
data = inp.readlines()
```

or

```
data = list(inp)
```

but the latter two will leave newline characters on each line, which tends to be undesirable.

Note that since you care about order, putting your strings into any sort of `set` is not advisable - that destroys order.

Answer (score 4):

Because file objects are iterable, you can just do:

```
with open("test.txt") as inp:
    data = list(inp) # or set(inp) if you really need a set
```

([documentation reference](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects))

Alternatively, more verbose (with list comprehension you can remove trailing newlines here also):

```
with open("test.txt") as inp:
    data = inp.readlines()
```

or (not very *Pythonic*, but gives you even more control):

```
data = []
with open("test.txt") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        data.append(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the readlines command which would return a list.

```
with open("test.txt") as inp:
    data = set(inp.readlines())
```

In case of the doing.

```
data = set(inp.read().split())
```

You are first reading the whole file as one string (inp.read()), then you are using split() on that which causes the string to be split on whitespaces.

Comment: I will be using text file with thousands of lines .... that means using inp.read().split() will not be a good choice, am I right ?

Comment: @VipulSharma Yes inp.read() from a file with thousands of line is not a good choice.